# Sink Stack Full - Saving Output of Table Function

Tags: r, file-io, dataframe, time-series

I have a folder full of files containing the same time series data. Here is a sample of my data:

```
Date        Time       Letter
2009-09-25  23:56:00   a
2009-09-25  23:57:00   a
2009-09-25  23:58:00   b
2009-09-25  23:59:00   c
2009-09-26  00:00:00   c
2009-09-26  00:00:00   c
2009-09-26  00:00:00   c
2009-09-26  00:00:00   b
2009-09-26  00:00:00   a
```

I am looking to apply my function to all files in the folder. Within this I will split each file into separate days using split by Date, and apply a function to these. I have then used table to return me the date followed by the number of each letter which is entered for that day. So for the data above I would get back:

```
$2009-09-25
a 2
b 1
c 1

$2009-09-26
a 1
b 1
c 3
```

My problem is that when I try to use sink to direct the output to a file, I get the error "sink stack is full".

```
setwd("C:\\User1\\Documents\\Files")
path <- "C:\\User1\\Documents\\Files"

files <- list.files(path = path)

lapply(files,function(files, path){
  path <- "C:\\User1\\Documents\\Files"

  fp <- file.path(path, files)
  df <- read.csv(fp)

#A few more calculations with data here

# Separating data frame into large list of separate days
eachday <- split(df, df$Date)

myfunction <- function(df){

# More calculations with data within function

#Sink output to file 
sink(file="testing121.csv", append=TRUE, type = "output", split=FALSE)
return(table(night$Activity))
}

# Apply function over list of days
lapply(eachday, myfunction)

})
```

It also doesn't work if I close the sink within the function. Is there a better way to save my data to a file with each specific date and the frequency of its Letter column? And why is this sink wrong?

Comment: `sink` is for writing the console output to a file. You want to use `write.csv` to build a CSV file of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting the `return` to output to the current file in `sink`. This is not how R works.

`return` returns a value to the calling function. It does not create any output. What you are probably trying to do is:

```
...
sink(file="foo.csv")
print(mydata)
sink()
}
```

ie set the sink, print something (which goes to the sink file) then reset the sink. You don't care about the return value so you don't use `return`.

As noted in comments, this isn't going to create a proper `.csv` file (it will look like the console output, with `[1] 10 20 30` and so on), so you really need to use `write.table` or `write.csv` and not use the `sink` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can get this working but I suppose the reason that I liked sinking the output of the table function was that it was the only way I seemed to be able to also get the corresponding date, which printing does not seem to do.